# S3 concurrent Range requests for large file transfer to browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser, download

According to [S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-byte-range-fetches.html) GET requests over 500 MB should use multiple range requests for better performance. From my experiments, using Transfer Acceleration plus range requests yields much faster downloads even with much smaller files.

We transfer files up to a few TB, and we do it from the browser.

Are there any libraries that provide this functionality already?